# Did not find "JAVADB_DRIVER_LABEL" in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: netbeans, ide

I have installed NetBeans IDE 8.0.2.

When I am importing .zip file of my old project on which I was working, it's showing

> "JAVADB_DRIVER_LABEL" could not be found (in projectNAME)

When I was adding that driver library it was not there in NetBeans' Library list. So what should I do to run my project ?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but for anyone searching in the future, here is my experience.  When I shared a project with a customer which used Derby database, they needed to load the Java DB Driver, which in my case includes the derby.jar, derbyclient.jar, and derbynet.jar files.  Until those where added, they got the JAVADB_DRIVER_LABEL error.  In Netbeans, to do this you can either locate the *.jar files I referenced and add them in your Libraries folder in the project as jars, or use the "add library" option (right click on Libraries, Add Library) and select the "Java DB Driver" library which will add the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem:

1. You need to right click library and click add library
2. Create library
3. Put name whatever you want
4. Add jar for class path
5. Choose -derby.jar -derbyclient.jar -derbynet.jar
6. OK
7. Go to the beginning and add the library which is created by you